# How to get a copy of whole element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I want to get the selected element and then insert it's copies in few places.

```
var template = $("#info-" + country + " > .stats > .template").clone();
$(template).insertBefore("#info-" + country + " > .stats > .template");
```

What I'm doing wrong that it doesn't copy the element and insert it?

P.S. The element which I'm selecting to copy is display:none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra wrap there, `template` is already a jQuery object, you just need:

```
var template = $("#info-" + country + " > .stats > .template").clone();
template.insertBefore("#info-" + country + " > .stats > .template");
```

Or a bit simpler:

```
var template = $("#info-" + country + " > .stats > .template");
template.clone().insertBefore(template);
```

Or use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) with a function, like this:

```
 $("#info-" + country + " > .stats > .template").before(function() { 
   return $(this).clone(); 
 });
```

Comment: Hmmm, tried the 3rd example and nothing happened.. Live example: http://apps.starchat.ee/stats.php

Comment: @Richards - your selector doesn't match your markup, there's a `.map` in there, like this: `$("#instance-" + country + " > .content > .stats > .map > .template")`

Comment: Bwaah, I didn't even pay attention to it- I thought it checks all children, doesn't it? Big thanks! :)

Comment: Nevermind, now it makes sense.. " > " is direct children only.. Ops.